# Display MongoDB database on WebPage directly using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb, web

I have a mongoDB database containing information for file(photos) address location on my hard drive - I want to show that on a web page.
I know I can export my mongodb data into a JSON file using query as
follows

`mongoexport --db AppDB --collection files --pretty --out d:/output.json`

Now the one of the part of problem is this above query - for it to run - the address window/`cmd prompt/shell` location should be   `C:\MongoDB\Server\3.4\bin\`
I want to automate this using javascript or similar. Thanks

Comment: didn't got youu

Comment: That's not the way to procede. You need a backend like Node.js to talk with your DB then some API from Node.js to the client to get responses from the DB.